# Add extra columns to the customer entity

Tags: sxa, sitecore-commerce, sxa-storefront

We recently migrating our current sitecore site to SXA with commerce. I have a user registration/login feature in the site. I want to extend the customer entity (Commerceuser) with some additional properties like Gender, Age, DOB,... and few some. I am able to do register/edit the profile with some inbuild properties like FirstName,LastName,..

After researching few blogs, I came to know that customer can be extended through Child views using Composer Template. From the business tool, I am able to create new properties and assign their raw values in the child view.

So I need to know how we can extend and edit the child views from the Controller feature.

I also tried a adding custom properties to the CommerceUser. But it doesn't work.

I am using CreateUser/UpdateUser methods from customers plugin.

Can anyone pls suggest me a solution for this?

Comment: See answer here: https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/6/t/9433